# jquery draggable containment doesn't work if draggable element has transformation applied

Tags: javascript, scroll, draggable, transform

I'm trying to use [JQuery Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement)'s `containment` feature but it doesn't seem to work if the object being contained has a transformation applied to it.

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/US2fr/

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tweaks to the `drag` function, I finally have a working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/GgUN9/2/

You can test this by changing the `scale` and `orig` values. If the `test` div is smaller than the `container` it will stay within it's bounds. If it's larger, you'll be able drag it around, but it will also stay in the bounds (i.e. you shouldn't ever see white space inside the `container`).

**UPDATE:**

I noticed today that the JSFiddle example above does not work if the CSS `left` and `top` values are not `0px` for the `test` div. I've fixed this and updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GgUN9/3/

Hopefully this will help someone in the future!

Comment: Dude. Thank you so much for posting that. Man. I've been trying for days to make this work. Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad I could help! It stumped me as well... :)